# Meteor: possible to hook into route/render events?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm wondering if Meteor has something similar to angular's `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', callback)` that would allow you to hook into route or render events in Meteor from the outside. The use case here is an analytics service not currently supported by [okgrow](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/analytics#page-views) that needs to execute certain code on page views. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: which router are you using and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: React Router, though I'd be curious to know the answer for Iron & Flow as well. The goal is that a third-party analytics service would be able to hook into routing events in order to execute functions on page views (what would normally be $(document).ready() or $locationChangeSuccess in angular).